# Redirect IIS folder to another server

Tags: iis, redirect

I've been searching for the correct solution for a while; it seems like this should be a simple thing, but I can't find clear examples or instructions.

I have a number of applications on an IIS Server (8.0 or later). I want to redirect certain paths to URLs on another server; not all applications will be redirected.

For example:

- myServer01/App01 will be redirected to dev-app01.mydomain.com
- myServer01/App02 will be redirected to dev-application2.mydomain.com
- myServer01/LegacyApp will remain as is.

Is this something that IIS Redirect can handle? Is URL Rewrite a better solution? Or do I need to do this by putting a default.htm page in the App01 and App02 folders? (Or, is there a better solution I haven't heard of?)

If Redirect is a good solution, how do you configure each folder?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing Folder? Add them to the corresponding rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really easy to do using Redirect. Redirect has a server level option, but it also has folder/application level options; the trick is you have to select the folder first and then you can apply setting for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Any or all of the above are possibilities. If you don't want to expose your back end server naming convention to the world a reverse proxy using AAR and URL Rewrite is a pretty common way to go.

Comment: That's great, but I still have no idea how to implement the redirect. As far as I can tell, the Redirect only has one destination - not one per folder.